# XSLT reorder and check if is empty

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I was wording how I could reorder the tag Rice:

- Move the tag `<Rice>long-grain</Rice>` to down and ***`<Rice>123</Rice>***` to up;
- Remove the third tag `<Rice>` or remove it in case it is empty like `<Rice/>` using XSLT:

```
    //Original XML
    <Company>
        <FarmName addressID="123465789">
            <Name xml:lang="en">Main Farm</Name>
            <Details>
                <Milk>Jodie Forster</Milk>
                <Bajra>ESRKSC</Bajra>
                <Rice>long-grain</Rice> //move to down
                <Rice>123</Rice> // move to up
                <Rice/> //remove if it is empty
                <Jowar>852</Jowar>
                <Lobia>WW</Lobia>
                <Maize>5240</Maize>
                <Masoor isoCode="US">123</Masoor>
            </Details>
            <Email>test@test.net</Email>
            <Phone>
                <TelephoneNumber>
                    <AreaOrCityCode/>
                    <Number>123456789<Number/>
                </TelephoneNumber>
            </Phone>
        </FarmName>
    </Company>
    
    //Desire XML
    <Company>
        <FarmName addressID="123465789">
            <Name xml:lang="en">Main Farm</Name>
            <Details>
                <Milk>Jodie Forster</Milk>
                <Bajra>ESRKSC</Bajra>
                <Rice>123</Rice>
                <Rice>long-grain</Rice>
                <Jowar>852</Jowar>
                <Lobia>WW</Lobia>
                <Maize>5240</Maize>
                <Masoor isoCode="US">123</Masoor>
            </Details>
            <Email>test@test.net</Email>
            <Phone>
                <TelephoneNumber>
                    <AreaOrCityCode/>
                    <Number>123456789<Number/>
                </TelephoneNumber>
            </Phone>
        </FarmName>
    </Company>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Please explain the **rule** by which you want the Rice elements to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

To switch the position of the first and second `<Rice>` element you can use the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="Rice" />           <!-- Remove all Rice elements (except those selected by more specific templates)-->

    <xsl:template match="Rice[1]">          <!-- Select only the first Rice element -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="../Rice[2]" />   <!-- Switch first and second -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="../Rice[1]" />   
      <xsl:copy-of select="../Rice[position()>2 and normalize-space()]" />  <!-- Copy the (non-empty) rest -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```